# How to Get my Custom Toolbar to popup when my Custom Extension is Enabled?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, development, extensions

I am developing a custom extension for ArcMAP in Arcgis 10, and would like to display my Custom Toolbar automatically instead of having the user to select it from the customize window. Is this possible?

Further more is it possible to hide the toolbar, when the extension is switched off from the Extensions window?

Comment: see also [this thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=62121#158950).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement @Kirk's answer, to show and hide the toolbar, you can try using [`ICommandBar.Dock`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00230000006t000000) and use the `esriDockToggle` constant (64) from the [`esriDockFlags`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/esriDockFlags_Constants/00230000001n000000/) enumeration to toggle its visibility. Have not tried this myself so if it doesn't work try some of the other constants.

Comment: While Kirk's answer was helpful, you answer about using ICommandBar.Dock, was what actually what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I think this can be done in your implementation of the setter for [IExtensionConfig.State](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/State_Property/0042000000rn000000/).  Since this gets called before the doc opens (and before the toolbar collection is initialized) your extension might need to listen to [IDocumentEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v000000nn000000).OpenDocument and NewDocument.  Accessing IDocument.Toolbars before one of these events has fired can cause problems.